# Problems using $base_url with a secure https page

Tags: ssl, drupal, https

I had a problem a couple weeks ago in which my domain/theme name was inserted to all my links, thus:

www.mytheme.com/mytheme/events
www.mytheme.com/mytheme/login

I asked here and it was suggested that I enable $base_url, and that fixed to problem.

The new problem is now that I'm trying to to use https on a couple pages, css and module javascript is loading as http on those pages. I confirmed that disabling $base_url resolved the "mixed content" problems, but I'd rather not to do that and put up with an extra element in my URLs.

Is there any way I can solve both of these issues? Or do I have to live with one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you have your ssl certificate configured probably; All you need to do to support (http/https mixed mode) is to set the value of `$conf['https']` inside your site's settings.php file to true.

```
$conf['https'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but adding this to settings.php didn't have any effect.